# Copy files exclude one folder

Tags: c#

Basically I want to copy everything within a folder excluding one folder, which happens to be where logs are stored for my program. (*I know I could just store logs elsewhere, but I have my reasons*). So far I have:

```
private void btnCopyFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Copy all the files
            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\xxx\yyy", "*.*",
                            SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            .Where(p => p != Logging.fullLoggingPath))
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"));
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logging.fullLoggingPath))
            {
                Logging.Log("All necessary files copied to C:\\bbb", w);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logging.fullLoggingPath))
            {
                Logging.Log("Error copying files, make sure you have permissions to access the drive and write to the folder.", w);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I modify this to exclude one specific folder within `\\xxx\yyy`

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: The exception is on the basis the file already exists, can I set a force overwrite on this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the name of the folder and skip it

```
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\xxx\yyy", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    String currentFolder = "";
    int lastSlash = newPath.LastIndexOf("\\");
    int secondLastSlash = newPath.Substring(0, newPath.Length - (newPath.Length - lastSlash)).LastIndexOf("\\")+1;
        currentFolder = newPath.Substring(secondLastSlash,(lastSlash-secondLastSlash))

    If(!currentFolder.Equals(NameOfFolderNotToInclude))
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"), true);
}
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logging.fullLoggingPath))
        {
            Logging.Log("All necessary files copied to C:\\bbb", w);
        }
```

lastSlash variable is the position of the last \ in the string which indicates the text after it is the actual file.  We then create a substring that removes everything after the last \ in the string to the path of the file.  This gives us a path up to the folder.  We then utilize the substring to find the next \ so that we can extract out just the specific folder.

so in a path such as C:\users\someone\desktop\test.txt
lastSlash would indicate the \ before test.txt
using this we create a substring that is equal to C:\users\someone\desktop
we then use the same method to find the last \ in this path
we combine it all together to extract the folder of desktop.

You can use Jim Mischel's suggestion as it is more user friendly and readable. Example using that below

```
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\xxx\yyy", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if(Path.GetDirectory(newPath) != PathToExclude)
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"), true);
}
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logging.fullLoggingPath))
        {
            Logging.Log("All necessary files copied to C:\\bbb", w);
        }
```

Comment: But GetFiles returns file names, not directory names. You have to extract the directory name from the full file name so that you can exclude all the files in that directory.

Comment: @JimMischel As documentation says: " GetFiles returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) you don't need to extract anything.

Comment: Please see udpdated code, any idea why it always "catches" on the catch try?

Comment: I have updated the code to show how you get the folder where the file sits although Jim Mischel has a better way to get the folder;   I will look at your updated code

Comment: @FrK  Post the exception that is being thrown

Comment: The exception is on the basis the file already exists, can I set a force overwrite on this command?

Comment: @FrK  as Alireza  stated there is a overloaded File.Copy method that will overwrite the file.  See his comments.  I will update to include the overwrite

Comment: Thanks, what exactly are the lastSlash and SecondLastSlash lines doing along with currentFolder = statement?

Comment: By the way, you can use `File.AppendAllText(filename, "All necessary...");` No need to open a `StreamWriter` if you're just appending a one string. See [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In your loop, just add a conditional to exclude that directory

```
If (Path.GetDirectory(newPath) == PathToExclude)
    Continue;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(@"\\xxx\yyy", "*.*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(p=>p!=Logging.fullLoggingPath))
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"));
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Logging.fullLoggingPath))
    {
         Logging.Log("All necessary files copied to C:\\bbb", w);
    }
```

Comment: You could also use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

Comment: Don't you have to extract the directory from the file name?

Comment: "Except" requires another IEnumerable<string>. I think Where is more sensible although both are working fine.

Comment: @JimMischel No because the log file resides where other files are in i.e they share same path.

Comment: @JimMischel GetFiles includes path into file names http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Comment: Please see udpdated code, any idea why it always "catches" on the catch try?

Comment: @FrK whould you please catch the thrown Exception and report what its message is

Comment: Yes, I know that it includes the path. My point is that you are checking for a single file name, and the user wants to exclude all files from a particular subdirectory. As written, your code will not work correctly.

Comment: @JimMischel No he wants to exclude only Log file ("Basically I want to copy everything within a folder **excluding one folder**...)

Comment: The exception is on the basis the file already exists, can I set a force overwrite on this command?

Comment: File.Copy has an overload by which you can force to overwrite existing file: File.Copy(...,...,true);

Comment: I think you will find that "excluding one folder" means "excluding one folder and all the files that it contains."